# What is a whip stall?

Tags: aircraft-performance, stall

I was reading [14 CFR 23.3](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=pt14.1.23#se14.1.23_13), which discusses airplane categories. In normal and commuter categories, stalls (except whip stalls) are allowed. The regulation, however does not define "whip stalls." What is meant by this term?

Comment: It happens very quickly. "Whip", then the aircraft stalls.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The clearest definition I could find is from [an AOPA quiz](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2000/December/1/Test-Pilot-%2812%29) (of all places):

> The airplane is pitched up into a vertical or near-vertical climb. It
>   then pauses, slips downward momentarily (tail first), and then whips
>   into a steep, nose-down attitude.

The tail-first slip backwards seems to be the defining characteristic of a whip stall. Interestingly, *Whip Stall and Tumble Awareness* is included in the [FAA's Powered Parachute and Weight Shift Control PTS](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-32.pdf), but they aren't defined there either.