# What are the differences between Normal and Utiltiy Categories

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-certification, aircraft-operations

In the operating handbooks for GA aircraft, there are often weight and balance limitations listed for both **Normal** and **Utiltity** category operation.  If I restrict the loading to the Utility category envelope, I want to know what regulations and prudence allow me to do over the Normal category envelope.

I am guessing that there are a set of regulatory certification standards for each category, as well as a list of specific restrictions for each type certificate.  What are these definitions and where are they found?

Comment: has the FAA removed the section in Part 23 on the utility category? I have tried searching in the most recent FARs on CFR.gov, and have not been able to find any definition of utility category or what it is capable of.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From a regulatory standpoint the governing regulation is FAR 23 (airworthiness standards for what we'd generally call "small" airplanes - Normal, Utility, Acrobatic, and Commuter category).

[FAR 23.3](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.3.10.1.59.3) is probably what you're interested in, and tells us:

- **Normal Category** is limited to airplanes that have a seating configuration, excluding pilot seats, of nine or less, a maximum certificated takeoff weight of 12,500 pounds or less, and intended for nonacrobatic operation.
  They go on to specify that nonacrobatic operation includes:

  - Any maneuver incident to normal flying
    (for very vanilla definitions of "normal" - they expect you to use some common sense here!)
  - Stalls (except ["whip stalls"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18859/what-is-a-whip-stall))
  - What most pilots recognize as the "commercial flight test maneuvers": Lazy eights, chandelles, and steep turns, but with an angle of bank not greater than 60 degrees in any of these maneuvers.
- **Utility Category** is the same type and size of airplane, but approved for "limited acrobatic operations" - this *may* include intentional spins, as well as the "commercial maneuvers" with higher bank angles (greater than 60 degrees, up to 90 degrees).
- **Acrobatic Category** is the same type and size of airplane, but approved for acrobatics  without any restrictions "other than those shown to be necessary as a result of required flight tests" -- basically "airplanes that can go upside-down".

The commuter category is boring: It's basically the normal category, but with more engines (at least 2) and more seats (up to a maximum of 19). Commuter category aircraft can also have a higher maximum takeoff weight (up to 19,000 pounds).

An aircraft can be certificated in any combination of the Normal, Utility, and Acrobatic categories if the aircraft meets the requirements of the appropriate category (as specified later in FAR 23).  An aircraft certificated in the Commuter category may not be certificated in any of the other categories however.

---

Generally the restrictions you find on aircraft are not regulatory ones (from the FARs) but Operating Limitations (in the POH or placarded on the aircraft) which you must comply with (per Part 91 of the FARs).

For example, the Cessna 172 and the Piper Warrior are both dual-category aircraft (Normal and Utility), and specify a "Utility Category CG Envelope" in their weight and balance charts.

The Piper Warrior is *not* approved for spins in the utility category (they are placarded with `SPINS PROHIBITED`). they also have other restrictions for utility category operations which are found in the POH and on aircraft placards (e.g. `UTILITY CATEGORY - NO BAGGAGE OR AFT PASSENGERS`, and maximum entry speeds for other acrobatic maneuvers).

Most Cessna 172s *are* approved for spins in the utility category and are not placarded against them. (Certain aircraft with specific STOL kits installed are *disapproved* as a result of the kit, and have placards prohibiting them).

Comment: has the FAA removed the section in Part 23 on the utility category? I have tried searching in the most recent FARs on CFR.gov, and have not been able to find any definition of utility category or what it is capable of.

Comment: I think the info you are looking for was in § 23.2005 Certification of normal category airplanes. It was rewritten sometime after 1996 to remove the utility category but lots of FAA Books and ACs still refer to it. The POH or AFM of many aircraft certified under CAR3 still refer to the utility category when determining the W&B for commercial maneuvers. 
This site has an old version. https://www.ascentgroundschool.com/faa-references/fars/107-part-23-airworthiness-standards-normal-utility-acrobatic-and-commuter-category-airplanes#14:1.0.1.3.10.2.59.2